# memory allocated in assembly using malloc - want to convert it to a3-D array in C++

Tags: c++, assembly

I have an assembly segment of the program that does a huge malloc (typically of the order of 8Gb), populates it and does computations on it.

For debugging purposes I want to be able to convert this allocated and pre-filled memory as a 3-D array in C/C++. I specifically do not want to allocate another 8 GB because declaring `unsigned char* debug_arr[crystal_size][crystal_size][crystal_size]` and doing an element-by-element copy will result in a stack overflow.

I would ideally love to type cast the memory pointer to an 3D array pointer ... Is it possible ?

Objective is to verify the computation results done in Assembly segment.

My C/C++ knowledge is average. I mostly use 64-bit assembly, so request give me the C++ typecasting in some detail, please?

Env : Intel Core i7 2600K @4.4 GHz with 16 GB RAM, 64 bit assembly programming on 64 bit Windows 7, Visual Studio Express 2012

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access a single `unsigned char` entry as if from a 3D array, you obviously need the relevant dimensions (call them `nXDim`, `nYDim`, `nZDim` for the sake of argument) and you need to know what dimension order has been assumed during writing.

If we assume that `z` changes less frequently than `y` and `y` less frequently than `x` then you can access your array via a function such as this:

```
unsigned char* GetEntry(int nX, int nY, int nZ)
{
    return &pYourArray[(nZ * nXDim * nYDim) + (nY * nXDim) + nX];
}
```

Comment: If the dimensions are known at compile time, then a type cast should work.

Comment: @brian - the type cast is not working. The typecast code is as here : unsigned char * debug_cube[2044][2044][2044] = (unsigned char *)(crystal_cube); and the C++ complaint is : Error 3 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char *' to 'unsigned char *[2044][2044][2044]'...

Comment: @Roger - This is not about getting a specific element - the assembly stretch computes Hamiltonian (essentially, for each cell, how many it does not match to in its immediate neighbourhood). I wanted to check the value back in C, so have to iterate all over the cube. Typecast would be the dream solution, if its possible ...

Comment: @user1104214 - ok, sorry, I misunderstood your question then.

Comment: @user1104214 you're doing cast incorrectly. See brian beuning answer for a correct cast

Answer (score 1):

First check what orderin is done in your memory . there are two types raw major orderin or column major

```
For row major ordering
Address = Base + ((depthindex*col_size+colindex) * row_size + rowindex) * Element_Size
For column major ordering
Address = Base + ((rowindex*col_size+colindex) * depth_size + depthindex) * Element_Size
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you to expand on:

```
char array[10000];    // One dimensional array
char * mat[100];      // Matrix for 2D array
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    mat[i] = array + i * 100;
```

Now, you have the matrix as a 100x100 element 2D array in the same memory as the array.

Comment: this will require two allocations I think .. In any case, the error is shown by compiler.. I have listed it to the response to Brian on typecast

Comment: See my comment on Brian's post.  You need to somehow save the pointers.  In C++, a 2D array is composed of pointers to pointers.  That is what I tried to show you.  You will have to extrapolate to 3D array from there. I think Roger's answer will suit you if you do not want to allocate extra memory for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dimensions at compile time, then something like this

```
void * crystal_cube = 0; // set by asm magic;
typedef unsigned char * DEBUG_CUBE[2044][2044][2044];
DEBUG_CUBE debug_cube = (DEBUG_CUBE) crystal_cube;
```

Comment: ISO C++ forbids casting to an array type.  The third statement will not compile.